# how to retrieve a table with many tables with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Recently I've been using PDO

and I'd like to get a table with hasmany related table.

I can get a table with the tables like this

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'order_id' => '170',
     'purchase_id' => '222',
     'product_option_id' => '014',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'order_id' => '170',
     'purchase_id' => '600',
     'product_option_id' => '015',
  )),
)
```

with SQL query like this

```
SELECT ord.order_id,puc.purchase_id,puc.product_option_id
FROM order ord
JOIN purchase puc
ON ord.order_id = puc.order_id
WHERE ord.order_id = '170'
```

However I'd like to get this data like this

```
array (
  0 => 
  array(
     'order_id' => '170',
     'purchase_id' => '222',
     'purchase' => array(
         0 =>
         array(
             'purchase_id' => '222',
             'product_option_id' => '014',
         ),
         1 =>
         array(
             'purchase_id' => '600',
             'product_option_id' => '015',
         ),
      )
   )
)
```

How do get the data like this with PDO?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you need to iterate and transform it element by element. Tried that yet?

Comment: I didn't tried yet. I didn't even think about that. I thought I could get it with pure SQL query.

Comment: SQL can't produce a two-level structure. It's always rows and columns.

Comment: @tadman SQL can't but PDO can ;) That's one of the things for which I am so excited about my tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, [you CAN have it with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group).

Were you need anything but id from orders, the mission were impossible.

But as long as you need only unique value from orders, you can get the thing like this

```
array (
  170 => 
  array(
         0 =>
         array(
             'purchase_id' => '222',
             'product_option_id' => '014',
         ),
         1 =>
         array(
             'purchase_id' => '600',
             'product_option_id' => '015',
         ),
      )
   )
)
```

with as simple code as

```
$sql = "your sql";
$pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

However, I see very little sense in fetching the same order ID usedto filter the data. May be it should be some other query that is closer to your real needs? Like one that is fetching several orders?

Comment: No I only needed one order with several purchase table. This is awesome!!! Thank you!!

Comment: @tadman it comes really handy when you need to group by date, or status or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it like this with PDO, but you can rearrange the results. A possible way to do it would be to use the [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function.

```
$orders = array_reduce($results, function ($carry, $item) {
    if (!isset($carry[$item->order_id])) {
        $carry[$item->order_id] = array(
            'order_id' => $item->order_id,
            'purchase' => array(array(
                'purchase_id' => $item->purchase_id,
                'product_option_id' => $item->product_option_id,
            ));
        );
    } else {
        $carry[$item->order_id]['purchase'][] = array(
           'purchase_id' => $item->purchase_id,
           'product_option_id' => $item->product_option_id,
        );
    }
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't even thought about this way.